# Neural networks: classification using Encog

Tags: neural-network, encog

I'm trying to get started using neural networks for a classification problem.  I chose to use the Encog 3.x library as I'm working on the JVM (in Scala).  Please let me know if this problem is better handled by another library.

I've been using resilient backpropagation.  I have 1 hidden layer, and e.g. 3 output neurons, one for each of the 3 target categories.  So ideal outputs are either 1/0/0, 0/1/0 or 0/0/1.  Now, the problem is that the training tries to minimize the error, e.g. turn 0.6/0.2/0.2 into 0.8/0.1/0.1 if the ideal output is 1/0/0.  But since I'm picking the highest value as the predicted category, this doesn't matter for me, and I'd want the training to spend more effort in actually reducing the number of wrong predictions.

So I learnt that I should use a softmax function as the output (although it is unclear to me if this becomes a 4th layer or I should just replace the activation function of the 3rd layer with softmax), and then have the training reduce the cross entropy.  Now I think that this cross entropy needs to be calculated either over the entire network or over the entire output layer, but the `ErrorFunction` that one can customize calculates the error on a neuron-by-neuron basis (reads array of ideal inputs and actual inputs, writes array of error values).  So how does one actually do cross entropy minimization using Encog (or which other JVM-based library should I choose)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm also working with Encog, but in Java, though I don't think it makes a real difference. I have similar problem and as far as I know you have to write your own function that minimizes cross entropy.

And as I understand it, softmax should just replace your 3rd layer.

Comment: Well, how to write that cross entropy minimizing error function *correctly* is exactly the question.  Any ideas?  If you have a Java implementation that's fine.

Comment: Hi, these two links are now dead. Would you have current links for these two pages on HeatonResearch ?

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't find it.